# How to set value to header from another html

Tags: javascript, html

I have `index.html` in which I have some header/footer code and one `iframe` in which I am loading different html pages like `one.html`,`two.html`.

I have slider on `one.html` page which value I need to set to `span` which is in header of `index.html` but I am getting issues like.

```
index.js:624 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

I have added js file in `one.html` like

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/one.js"></script>
```

Here is code in index.js

```
function setTemprature(Temprature){
    var tempText = document.getElementById("TempText"); 
    tempText.innerHTML = Temprature;                
}
```

and span in `index.html`

```
<span id="TempText" class="page-title label center-block">HI</span>
```

and I am calling this function from one.js

```
if(clicked_btn_id == "btn-temp-up"){                
    if(Temprature < 80){
        setTemprature();
    }
}
```

I am newbie on javascript and html. Please suggest me.

Comment: You have 2 separated files, one.html and index.html. You included the scripts in one.html therefore you won't access the elements in index.html.

Comment: "_`span` ... is in header_" It shouldn't, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @Teemu ,@Rax alternate solution for this?